# NodeJS unable to process request with header > 8KB

Tags: node.js

We are using Node 6.10 and whenever any request with header size > 8 KB comes to Node Server then it throws some proxy error. Is there any option to increase the request header size with Node v6.10?

Comment: Is your issue related to this : https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/24692 ? What module are you using for your server ? in-built `http`, `express`, or something else ?

Comment: we are using express

Comment: Are you sure this happens in node 6? The options are for a newer version: https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_max_http_header_size_size